# ¿ Como puedo pasar un ciclo en php a sintaxis de twig?

Tags: php, bucle-for, twig

Tengo el siguiente ciclo for en php y quiero pasarlo a sintaxis de twig,alguien puede darme algun consejo o donde puedo encontrar la respuesta, gracias.

```
     $end_year = $current_year - 200;
     for($i=$current_year;$i>$end_year;$i--):
      ...
     endfor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
{%  set current_year = 15 %}
{%  set end_year = current_year - 200 %}

{% for i in current_year..end_year %}
     {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, de acuerdo con [answer], te invito a editar y explicar tu respuesta de modo que comprendamos como tu script soluciona el problema